# Como melhorar minha validação de entrada e saída

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a função `inserir`, e nela tem uma validação de entrada e saída, primeiro ela faz um `select` com a função `count` com um `where` referenciando o código do produto, depois ela cai na condição  `if($quantidade_db >= $quantidade || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)` se a quantidade do banco for maior ou igual quantidade inserida pelo usuário ou se  `mysqli_num_rows == 0` ela vai para a inserção, se a condição for falsa, mostra uma mensagem na tela "valor ultrapassa a quantidade em estoque".

A validação funciona para a saída, mas para entrada, por exemplo, o usuário cadastra o produto com a flag de entrada duas vezes com a quantidade de 50, mas novamente ele cadastra o mesmo produto com a flag de entrada mas com a quantidade de 101, a vai aparecer a mensagem "valor ultrapassa a quantidade em estoque".

Na entrada o usuário deve digitar a quantidade que ele quiser, e não cair no `else` para exibir a mensagem.

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema, ou melhorar a validação?

O código:

```
<?php

require_once('./base_de_dados/connect_bd.php');

function inserir(){
    //Conectando com o banco de dados
    $dbc = conexao();

    $retorno = array();

    $erros = array();
    $admin;
    $produto;
    $registro;
    $quantidade;

    //função empty verifica se não tem registro inserido

    if($_POST['produto'] == ""){
        $erros[] = 'O campo codigo administrador é obrigatório!';
    }else{
        $produto = $_POST['produto'];
    }

    if($_POST['admin'] == ""){
        $erros[] = 'O campo codigo produto é obrigatório $teste!';
    }else{
        $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    }

    if($_POST['registro'] == ""){
        $erros[] = 'O campo Registro é obrigatório!';
    }else{
        $registro = $_POST['registro'];
    }

    if(empty($_POST['quantidade'])){
        $erros[] = 'O campo quantidade é obrigatório!';
    }else{
        $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
    }

       if(empty($erros)){
      $query = "select SUM(ret.quantidade) AS quantidade,
            ret.nome_produto,
            ret.id_produto
            from(SELECT 
            SUM(p.quantidade) AS QUANTIDADE, 
                p.tipo_registro, 
                p.id_produto, 
                c.nome AS nome_produto, 
                c.imagem
                FROM estoque p JOIN administrador u 
                           ON u.id_admin = p.id_admin 
                           JOIN cadastro_produtos c 
                           ON c.id_produto = p.id_produto
                           WHERE p.tipo_registro = 'entrada'

                           GROUP BY                 
                           p.tipo_registro, 
                           p.id_produto, 
                           c.nome, 
                           c.imagem 
                           UNION
                           SELECT 
                           -SUM(p.quantidade) AS QUANTIDADE, 
                           p.tipo_registro, 
                           p.id_produto, 
                           c.nome AS nome_produto, 
                           c.imagem 
                           FROM estoque p JOIN administrador u 
                           ON u.id_admin = p.id_admin 
                           JOIN cadastro_produtos c 
                           ON c.id_produto = p.id_produto
                           WHERE p.tipo_registro = 'saida'

                           GROUP BY                 
                           p.tipo_registro, 
                           p.id_produto, 
                           c.nome, 
                           c.imagem)ret
                           WHERE ret.id_produto = $produto
                           group by ret.nome_produto,
                           ret.id_produto";





        $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $quantidade_db = $row['quantidade'];


         if($quantidade_db >= $quantidade || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){

        //inserir no banco de dados
        $query = "INSERT INTO estoque(id_estoque, quantidade, tipo_registro, id_admin, id_produto, dt_movimentacao) VALUES (NULL, $quantidade,'$registro', '$admin' ,'$produto',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

        $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        echo "$query";


        if($result){
            $retorno[] = 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso!';

        }else{
            $erros[] = 'Ocorreu algum erro ao cadastrar o estoque!';
        }
        /** if($quantidade_db <= $quantidade || mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0){

        //inserir no banco de dados
        $query = "INSERT INTO estoque(id_estoque, quantidade, tipo_registro, id_admin, id_produto, dt_movimentacao) VALUES (NULL, $quantidade,'$registro', '$admin' ,'$produto',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

        $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        echo "$query";


        if($result){
            $retorno[] = 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso!';

        }else{
            $erros[] = 'Ocorreu algum erro ao cadastrar o estoque!';
        }


    }else{

        //erro estoque
        echo"<script>alert('Primeiro Digite a entrada'); history.go(-1)</script>";
    }
            **/

    }else{

        //erro estoque
        echo"<script>alert('Valor Ultrapassa a quantidade em estoque'); history.go(-1)</script>";
    }


    }else{

        $retorno = $erros;

    }

    return $retorno;
}?>
```

Comment: Informações não relevantes a pergunta devem ser adicionadas nos comentários. Como por exemplo "_se eu não fui claro, me peçam mais informações_". Comece aprendendo mais sobre o Stackoverflow visitando o [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).